# How to dynamically access D3.js promise.all use page onclick event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I de-couple 'retrieving data' and 'using data' when using D3.js `promise.all`?

For example, if I get two csv files using D3.js `promise.all` as shown below, I can successfully access data inside scope of `then(function(data) {`

```
var file1 = "file1.csv"
var file2 = "file2.csv"

Promise.all([
    d3.csv(file1),
    d3.csv(file2)
]).then(function(data) {
    var file1 = data[0];
    var file2 = data[1];

    // I can then use data in var file1 and file 2 in charts etc

});
```

However, I would like to separate the  'retrieving data' and 'using data', so I do not have retrieve all data files when I want to dynamically change how I am using the data.

For example, say I have a chart currently inside scope of `then(function(data) {` and I want to dynamically change which of two the `promise` data sets it uses.

How can I simply refer to the `promise` data as a function or object from another function that is not in its scope?

Something like having two buttons to dynamically change chart data from file1 to file2 that would refer to `promise` data as objects.

```
<html>
<body>

    <input type="button" onclick="getfile2();" value="file1">​

    <input type="button" onclick="getfile2();" value="file2">

    <script src="d3data.js"></script>

    <div id="mychart"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on click of button, what you want to do?

Comment: Will update question, but this is about scope, and question should be how to de-couple 'getting data' and 'using data'. I don't want to re-run entire retrieval of all data files, when I only want to dynamically switch which one I am using.

Comment: Let me try to prepare a small demo.

Comment: was following answer helpful?

Comment: yes thanks, seeing `renderData` gives me insight into accessing `promise` but still looking for something bit more generic eg button click to send var name eg `file1` and then it retrieves that without need for `if then else`

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm not working for me. I don't understand how `renderData` function knows about `fileData`

Comment: Because we have declared the fileData variable as a global variable. It’s not working or you don’t understand how it works?

Comment: Ok great it works, had typo, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML file as given by you with a slight function call change:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="renderData(0);" value="file1">​
    <input type="button" onclick="renderData(1);" value="file2">
    <script src="d3data.js"></script>
    <div id="mychart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

d3data.js file should look like:

```
var file1 = "file1.csv";
var file2 = "file2.csv";

var fileData = null;

function renderData(dataIndex) {

    //ignore click events until data is being loaded
    if(fileData == null) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("mychart").data = fileData[dataIndex];
}

Promise.all([
    d3.csv(file1),
    d3.csv(file2)
]).then(function(data) {
    fileData = data;

    // then use data in charts etc
    // chart - want to dynamically change data source
    // from file1 to file2 and back using button onClick event
    // by default render first file, 0 index
    renderData(0);

});
```

Comment: What would you call using `renderData()` function here? Is this what is referred to as a `callback`?

Comment: I modified this to be more generic by defining `var data = data` in `promise` and then in `renderData` I can now refer to `data[0], data[1]`

Comment: actually renderData() is the function which will switch the data ofo chart between different files according to the parameter passed. What I am doing is, when .then(...) calls, I store data in global variables and then reusing them on click events.

Comment: Yeah that is better, more adjustments could be done, I just prepared a small demo which is easy to understand. Good work.

Comment: So how would I call `renderData` from another function say an `onClick` to specify which `data[n]` to use?

Comment: I have already done that, try to run my example, you will understand. If you see html, I am passing 1 for file1 and 2 for file2, you can do the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213036/discussion-between-curtisp-and-hamza-arshad).